# Oracle Table partition goes well with which index

Tags: sql, oracle, indexing, create-table, partition

I have a transactions table where 200 GB data stored and having 5 years of data. We have partitioned the table based on the transaction date and we observed the performance is very slow. Before partition the report running for 40 mins now running for 1hr 45 mins.   We have created the Local non-partitioned index and this table having almost 10 local non-partitioned indexes.

There is two more child table for the header and the same txn date field is present in both the tables and we have used the same partition in those two tables.

Can I use a global index?

```
-- Prompt Create Table
CREATE TABLE TC_TXN_NEW
   (TC_TXN_IID NUMBER(12,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    TC_SETTLEMENT_IID NUMBER(8,0), 
    MD_BUCKET_IID NUMBER(10,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    MD_MEDIA_IID NUMBER(9,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    MD_MEDIA_UTC NUMBER(5,0), 
    TXN_TYPE NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    TXN_DATE DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    TXN_SOURCE NUMBER(2,0) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    TXN_EXT_REF VARCHAR2(50 CHAR), 
    ORIG_PURCH_AMT NUMBER(21,4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    DISC_AMT NUMBER(21,4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    RDM_AMT NUMBER(21,4) DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    AWD_AMT NUMBER(21,4) NOT NULL ENABLE, 
    ...........
    SETTLE_PROC_REQ NUMBER(1,0) DEFAULT '1', 
    OCE_DISCOUNT_RULE NUMBER(1,0), 
    OCE_RDM_POOL_TYPES VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
    OCE_RDM_ECPN_TYPES VARCHAR2(3 CHAR), 
    OCE_CANCEL_REASON NUMBER(2,0), 
    USER_IID NUMBER(8,0), 
    PROCESS_DATE_UTC DATE NOT NULL ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT PK_TC_TXN PRIMARY KEY (TC_TXN_IID) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT FK_MD_BUCKETIID FOREIGN KEY (MD_BUCKET_IID) REFERENCES MD_BUCKET (MD_BUCKET_IID) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT FK_TC_TXN_SETTLEMENTIID FOREIGN KEY (TC_SETTLEMENT_IID) REFERENCES TC_SETTLEMENT (TC_SETTLEMENT_IID) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT FK_TC_TXN_MEDIAIID FOREIGN KEY (MD_MEDIA_IID) REFERENCES MD_MEDIA (MD_MEDIA_IID) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT FK_TCTXN_TERMINALID FOREIGN KEY (TERMINAL_ID) REFERENCES TERMINAL (TERMINAL_ID) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT FK_TCTXN_MERCHANTID FOREIGN KEY (MERCHANT_ID) REFERENCES MERCHANT (MERCHANT_ID) ENABLE, 
     CONSTRAINT FK_TCTXN_CORPORATEID FOREIGN KEY (CORPORATE_ID) REFERENCES CORPORATE (CORPORATE_ID) ENABLE
   )  PARTITION BY RANGE (TXN_DATE) 
  INTERVAL(NUMTOYMINTERVAL(1, 'MONTH'))  -- per month partition 
  SUBPARTITION BY HASH (TC_SETTLEMENT_IID) SUBPARTITIONS 16 
  ( PARTITION P0_TCTXN VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-4-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
      PARTITION P1_TCTXN VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-5-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
      PARTITION P2_TCTXN VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-6-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')),
      PARTITION P3_TCTXN VALUES LESS THAN (TO_DATE('1-7-2013', 'DD-MM-YYYY')))
  TABLESPACE TS_XLS_TC;

  -- Create Index 
  CREATE INDEX IDX_TC_TXN_SETTLEPROCREQ ON TC_TXN (SETTLE_PROC_REQ) LOCAL COMPUTE STATISTICS TABLESPACE TS_XLS_TC;
  CREATE INDEX IDX_TC_TXN_MERCHANTIDTXNDATE ON TC_TXN (MERCHANT_ID, TXN_DATE) LOCAL COMPUTE STATISTICS TABLESPACE TS_XLS_TC;
  CREATE INDEX IDX_TCTXN_TXN_DATE ON TC_TXN (TXN_DATE) LOCAL COMPUTE STATISTICS TABLESPACE TS_XLS_TC;
```

Please suggest what type of index required here.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. You say "...the performance is very slow". Please **edit your question** using the `edit` button just below the tags and include an example of a query which is slow along with the query plan generated by the database for that query. Also, collect statistics on this table - i.e. run `DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS('your-schema-name', 'TC_TXN_NEW')` and see if that helps.

Comment: Are you able to provide query plans for those reports?
Also table definitions for those included in plan would be useful

Comment: What is the reason for HASH partition?

Comment: The best index depends on the query. If you have a query that returns a small percentage of rows, and the query specifies the partitions keys, then a local index works best, because there will only be one small local index to use. But if that query does *not* specify the partition keys, and partition pruning cannot be used, then the query must read 64 small local indexes instead of one large global index.  Since index access time grows logarithmically slow, traversing one large index can be much faster than traversing many small indexes.  (It's a difficult concept, I hope I explained it well.)

Comment: Reason for hash partition due to the use the field in the query along with Txn Date

Comment: Thank you all for your comments, Right now i have changed the query with Global index and it worked little fast compare to the local one.  Is it necessary to partition the index too with keys?

Comment: Also you say the table has "10 local non-partitioned indexes" but a local index **is** a partitioned index; did you mean you have 10 global indexes?